# To display a div on a particular point in the background in responsive webdesign

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am making a responsive website, and would like to display a div on a particular point in the background. But when I resize the browser, the div moves to a random location. 
https://jsfiddle.net/gmr2583u/ (couldn't attach the background image in the fiddle)
Background Image:
[blue background with a gray stamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pGbl.jpg).
Heres the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="jsfiddle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style>
        body{margin:0 auto;padding:0;font: 0.8em Arial,sans-serif;}
       .jsfiddle {
          float:left;
          display:block;
          background-image: url(Images/jsfiddle.jpg); 
          width:45%; 
          height:240px; 
          z-index:1; }
         .con1{
           float:right;
           padding:6% 2% 0 0;}
         .con1 a{
           text-decoration:none;
           font-weight:bold;
           color:#1f5198; 
           padding-top:1%;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="jsfiddle">
        <div class="con1"><a href="#">Click here for <br> information on 
          <br> CEO<br> Conference <br> October 9-10 </a>
        </div>
    </div>                    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use `position:absolute` on `.con1` and then tranform the element by minus of the `.con1` position percentage to account for the width and height of the element. You would also need to apply `position:relative;` to `.jsfiddle` so `.con1` is posititoned relative to that element.

```css
body{
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0;
  font: 0.8em Arial,sans-serif;
 }

.jsfiddle {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  display:block;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center center;
  background-image: url(http://www.placecage.com/c/460/300); 
  width:45%; 
  height:240px; 
  z-index:1; 
}
.con1 {
  position:absolute;
  right:6%;
  top:10%;
  transform:translate(-10%, -2%);
  background:#fff;
}
.con1 a{
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#1f5198; 
  padding-top:1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="jsfiddle">
  <div class="con1"><a href="#">Click here for <br> information on <br> CEO<br> Conference <br> October 9-10 </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I still couldn't get the div-text to exactly reside within the gray stamp, but made the gray stamp the back ground for the div, then used your code and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much!!